# How to build old soapui 3 version

Tags: java, maven, soapui

Latest version has pom file but old version not so how to build version 3 http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/3.0.1/

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by pop file? and on which version? there is latest 5.1.2 release of Open source, may be you would like to try before checking old version? If you still have version, probably you may report issue in http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/bd-p/SoapUI_OS forum

Comment: I think he means `pom` file.

Comment: @Raghuram right!, for sure means `pom` `:)`.

Comment: @albciff sorry yes it's pom, android keyboard changed it :)

Comment: @Rao I don't want soapui 5 for some reasons so I really want to build soapui 3 not 5

Comment: I had a look at the contents of the zip. There is a `build.xml` which would suggest [tag:ant], and there is a `maven.xml` which would suggest [tag:maven]. So I have to ask: What have you tried before just blasting an empty question out here?

Comment: @SiKing I tried maven as written in their documentation on github but thear doc worss only for v5. I will try Ant then tomorrow